# Method not called when launched

Tags: android, android-studio

so I'm kinda new to android developing.

I read [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-button-example/) as my reference to have a clickable button, with some changes in my xml. The problem that I have is, whenever I tried to click it, nothing happens. There's no error message on my phone nor android studio. I wonder what's missing or is there something that I don't know, that I should know?

Here's my java on my project

```
public class test_button extends Activity {
Button button ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_button);
    click();
}
public void click(){
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        Intent browserIntent =
                                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://reddit.com"));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

and this is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<include layout="@layout/layout_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"/>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/profile_page_activity_body"
    android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:text="Do things"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_greenbox"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit1 : on onClick(), i did try Toast, but it had similar outcome, nothing happened.

Edit2 : there's a click animation on button whenever i click it

Comment: How are you running this? In an emulator? On your device?

Comment: Not sure but change android:id="@+id/button", in this instead of setting id as button use some other like btn_do_things or something you wise to give but not button. In .java i.e. your activity class button is fine. Also can you pl tell your exact import line for OnClickListener?

Comment: @JoshuaCarmody   on my device. I tried on 2 devices, both have similar result

Comment: can you pl tell your exact import line for OnClickListener?

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela sorry, but what do you mean "exact import line" ? the "import android.view.View.OnClickListener" ?

Comment: Please don't use the term _function_ here. It's called a **method**

Comment: Could you try to change `new OnClickListener` to `new View.OnClickListener`?

Comment: @Amy still act the same way

Comment: But you see your `Button` on your Screen, and it has some Click Animation? (`Ripple`, Color change..)

Comment: Could you try this:  `Intent browserIntent =
                                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);` `browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://reddit.com"));` 
                        `startActivity(browserIntent);`

Comment: @Amy still has no effect whatsoever

Comment: It is possible there's something in the `layout_toolbar` you're including that conflicts? Do you have an `r.id.button` in there as well? Can you post the code to that layout file?

Answer (score 0):

call intent like this may in your link have a problem:

into click:-

```
**Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, 
           Uri.parse("https://www.reddit.com/"));
    startActivity(i);**
```

Just Put a **https://www.reddit.com/**  instead of **http://www.reddit.com/**

Comment: changing it to https still do nothing.

Comment: In above Link simple get text from edit-text. in your case you can directly pass URL into intent. hope it's works for you.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting click listener as:

```
public class TestButton extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Intent code here;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the onclick listenter inside the `onCreate` instead of that method and try.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_button);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        Intent browserIntent =
                                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://reddit.com"));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

Also, `test_button` is not a good name for a class. Change it to `TestButton`. (Rename using refactoring [shift+f6], so that you do not get reference errors)